# Running Xamarin iPhone app on iPad as an iPad application

Tags: ios, iphone, xaml, ipad, xamarin

I am learning Xamarin and trying some code on iPad and iPhones, particularly the ones given on Xamarin Github page. I am successful in running the app on iPhone as they are configured as iPhone apps.

**My Problem:**

I want to run the same app on iPad simulator. But it is running on it as an iPhone app.Particularly I want to try out how AlertController differs when it runs on iPhone and iPad.

**More Background :**

I am an iOS developer in Xcode we can change the iPhone app to work on iPad as iPad application just by ticking the option in the build settings. (It would just work on iPad as an iPad app, and not as an iPhone app)

**REMEMBER** :

I want to run iPhone app in Xamarin as an iPad app on Ipad simulator but not as an iPhone app (because it causes everything starts looking very big and ugly).

**More Info** :

I know we can do this by ticking the app as both iPhone and iPad in Xamarin ,but in my case I want to do this **AFTER** the project has been created.
What I am expecting is some ticking here in some project settings or something else.(needless to say I have no source code to share)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Info.plist` and change the "Devices" drop-down to "Universal":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change textsize, padding, grid spacing etc ... with :

```
Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone or Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet
```

For example

```
 if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) {
        //change label textsize
        // layout views vertically
    } else {
        // layout views horizontally or use different Page
    }
```

For more stuff read : https://blog.xamarin.com/bringing-xamarin-forms-apps-to-tablets/

Comment: inline example to set fontsize  FontSize = ((Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) ? 12 : (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet) ? 16 : 16);